# get date as mm/dd/YY format and using rails 5 attibutes API store into database

Tags: attributes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have inherited cast_type datetime,following my app/models/dob_type.rb

```
class DobType < ActiveRecord::Type::Datetime
    def cast(value)
        old_format = value.split('/')
        new_format = old_format[2] + '-' + old_format[0] + '-' + old_format[1]
        super new_format
    end
 end
```

I have created a model called user and want to store mm/dd/YY string into datetime column into postgres.here is the code below.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    attribute :dob, DobType.new
end
```

and I am trying to create an user object as follows:

```
user = User.create({:name => 'Jr. Adam Joe', :dob => '01/05/2016'})
```

its giving me

```
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Type::Datetime
```

any wayout? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is that should be ActiveRecord::Type::DateTime instead of ActiveRecord::Type::Datetime?